# How to access to a created docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I see that several varieties of this question have been asked in StackOverflow, but unfortunately, I could not get help from any of them.

I have created a docker container with the following command within an Ubuntu operating system:

```
docker run --name hasan -it ubuntu:latest bash
```

Inside the docker image, I set up a new file system. Now, I would like to reach the same container to continue to setup my filesystem inside.

How I can do it?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean? I have installed several packages, created some code files. I exit and enter again. They are there. They were not lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the running container with:

**docker exec -it hasan bash**

You might want to do the setup within a Dockerfile instead of doing it manually.